# Why is my shape distorted on rotation about the z axis?

Tags: ios, metal

I just started learning metal and can best show you my frustration with the following series of screenshots. From top to bottom we have
(1) My model where the model matrix is the identity matrix
(2) My model rotated 60 deg about the x axis with orthogonal projection
(3) My model rotated 60 deg about the y axis with orthogonal projection
(4) My model rotated 60 deg about the z axis

[image: My model where the model matrix is the identity matrix]

[image: My model rotated 60 deg about the x axis with orthogonal projection]

[image: My model rotated 60 deg about the y axis with orthogonal projection]
[image: My model rotated 60 deg about the z axis with orthogonal projection. So distorted :(! But why? Why?!]

So I use the following function for conversion into normalized device coordinates:

```
- (CGPoint)normalizedDevicePointForViewPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:point toCoordinateSpace:self.window.screen.fixedCoordinateSpace];
    CGFloat halfWidth = CGRectGetMidX(self.window.screen.bounds);
    CGFloat halfHeight = CGRectGetMidY(self.window.screen.bounds);
    CGFloat px = ( p.x - halfWidth ) / halfWidth;
    CGFloat py = ( p.y - halfHeight ) / halfHeight;
    return CGPointMake(px, -py);
}
```

The following rotates and orthogonally projects the model:

```
- (matrix_float4x4)zRotation
{
    self.rotationZ = M_PI / 3;
    const vector_float3 zAxis = { 0, 0, 1 };
    const matrix_float4x4 zRot = matrix_float4x4_rotation(zAxis, self.rotationZ);
    const matrix_float4x4 modelMatrix = zRot;

    return matrix_multiply( matrix_float4x4_orthogonal_projection_on_z_plane(), modelMatrix );
}
```

As you can see when I use the exact same method for rotating about the other two axes, it looks fine-not distorted. What am I doing wrong? Is there some sort of scaling/aspect ratio thing I should be setting somewhere? What things could it be? I've been staring at this for an embarrassingly long period of time so any help/ideas that can lead me in the right direction are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your rotation or projection matrices. The visual oddity arises from the fact that you move your vertices into NDC space prior to rotation. A rectangle doesn't preserve its aspect ratio when rotating in NDC space, because the mapping from NDC back to screen coordinates is not 1:1.

I would recommend not working in NDC until the very end of the vertex pipeline (i.e., pass vertices *into* your vertex function in "world" space, and *out* to the rasterizer as NDC). You can do this with a classic construction of the orthographic projection matrix that scales and biases the vertices, correctly accounting for the non-square aspect ratio of window coordinates.

Comment: "pass vertices into your vertex function in "world" space, and out to the rasterizer as NDC" REALLY helps me get my bearings. I had no idea as to the very basic structure of what I was doing. Thank you!